# Proof for set of 15 values that have property a−c=d−b

Tags: proof-explanation

I am pretty sure (please correct me if this is untrue), that in a set of 15 **different** values, ranging from integers (1-100), that there are four numbers, a,b,c,d such that a−c=d−b.

I have tried to understand why this is true, but just cannot wrap my head around it, any guidance on why this is the case (or if it isn't) would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a solution, but are you aware of the pigeon hole principle? A related and obvious question might be something like, "a set of 97 values from 1-100" has the desired property.

Comment: I am aware of the pigeonhole principle, maybe you could guide me on why this is true, even if you do not yet know? Sorry if that sounds confusing.

Comment: Could you try proving that in each set of $15$ numbers, there are two pairs with the same difference? Because $a-c=d-b\implies a+b=c+d$

Comment: Do you allow two of the numbers $a,b,c,d$ to be the same?

Comment: Oddly enough, I think it should work for $n\ge9$. Perhaps even $n=8$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel updated the question... yes different. There are number 1-100, not repeats.

Comment: Could you perhaps consider $a, b, 1,2,4,8,16,32$ and $64$?

Comment: @Raptor an optimal [Golomb Ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler#Known_optimal_Golomb_rulers) of length $12$ is easily adapted to a counterexample, but $n\ge13$ should work.

Comment: The usual pigeonhole approach: the set of 15 integers has 105 differences and there are only 99 possible differences, isn't quite enough. We'd also need to prove that any duplicated differences can't all be of the form $a-b=b-c$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was missing. For example $a=6$ mean $8-6=6-4$ which is a counterexample. Thanks for clearing that out

Comment: Perhaps $a, 1,2,4,6,8,12,16,24,32,48,64,96$ is the worst case scenario using $13$ different numbers.